# Remove divider line in PrimeNG calendar component

Tags: angular, sass, primeng

I'm using the PrimeNG calendar component. How (if possible) can I remove or change the color of the line/divider between the date-picker-header and the date-picker itself?

[image]

Basic Stackblitz with PrimeNG calendars all including the divider:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo?file=README.md

Calendar component in PrimeNG's github repo:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by overriding the component styles:

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-datepicker-header {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* or border-bottom-color: red; */
}
```

If you want to apply the style selectively, you can wrap this in an extra class:

```html
<p-calendar styleClass="no-divider"></p-calendar>
```

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-datepicker.no-divider .p-datepicker-header {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-6f4zjg?file=src/app/app.component.css)